# Scraping raw javascript and css files with Scrapy

Tags: html, url, scrapy, url-routing

I'd like to scrape all the linked javascript and css files on a give domain with Scrapy. The issue is that I don't quite understand how to extract the links from the link elements.

Assume I'm scraping example.com. There are links to js and css of the form:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path_to_css/example.css"/>
<script src="/path_to_js/example.js"></script>
```

These links start from the root domain, so no problem. But if the links are like the ones below, it starts to get confusing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_css/example.css"/>
<script src="path_to_js/example.js"></script>
```

These relative URLs are supposed to work such that if I'm on `example.com/some_page/` the link paths are appended to that like: `example.com/some_page/path_to_js/example.js`. That's not how it always works in actual web pages however. On some web sites with language selection eg.`example.com/en/some_page`, the relative paths start from `example.com/en` instead of the full path of that page.

So, while expecting to find the files at `example.com/en/some_page/path_to_js/example.js`, you find them at `example.com/en/path_to_js/example.js`

Is there any way to understand from where the relative paths start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While scraping, Scrapy allows you to create an absolute URL from a Relative URL

You could do something like this

```
for link in response.css("link"):
    response.urljoin(link.css("::attr(href)").extract_first())

for script in response.css("script"):
    response.urljoin(script.css("::attr(src)").extract_first())
```